# Css before, different content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to use plugin jauery, witch has css code like

```
.icon-eye:before {
content: '\56';
}
```

On plugin site - it's like eye. But When I install this plugin on my local pc - I have 'V', but not eye icon. Please help, how to fix it. Thaks.
[Plugin](http://tympanus.net/Development/PFold/index2.html)

Comment: Need to specify whats the problem could able to get what you are asking. May be `html` `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside your `<head>` fixes your problem

Comment: It's an 'V' because you don't have the image file of the 'eye' saved on your computer.

Comment: It's font problem, include the font where you work, or use [alt-code](http://alt-code.blogspot.com/)

Comment: @NischaalCooray its not an img its kind of icon font hopefully

Answer (score 2):

It's using an icon font, see beginning of [custom2.css](http://tympanus.net/Development/PFold/css/custom2.css):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'entypo-selected';
  src: url("../font/entypo-selected.eot");
  src: url("../font/entypo-selected.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), url("../font/entypo-selected.woff") format('woff'), url("../font/entypo-selected.ttf") format('truetype'), url("../font/entypo-selected.svg#entypo-selected") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo-selected';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.icon-eye:before { content: '\56'; } /* 'V' */
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the libraries are installed properly read the docs and installation guide and follow the instructions.